# Show multiple div elements on select using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I select the first option, I would like it to show the first input or div (already working) but now I need it for the 2nd option too and 3rd option too. I tried `else if` which didn't work.

```js
function optSelectEstimate(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("optnbestim1").value;
        if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("nbestim1").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("nbestim1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("nbestim1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="index-2.html">
                                            
  <!--Form Group-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="label">Étape #1</label>
    <select style="width:250px;" onchange="optSelectEstimate(this);">
    <option>Type de Service</option>
    <option id="optnbestim1" value="fenetre">Fenêtres (panneau traditionnel)</option>
    <option id="optnbestim2" value="gouttiere">Gouttières</option>
    <option id="optnbestim3" value="lavagepression">Lavage à pression du revêtement extérieur</option>
    </select>
  </div>
                                            
  <!--Form Group-->
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label">Étape #2</label>
      <div id="nbestim1" style="display: none;">
      <input type="number" name="nbestim1" placeholder="Unités"></div>
      <div id="nbestim2" style="display: none;">
      <input type="number" name="nbestim2" placeholder="Pied linéaire"></div>
      <div id="nbestim3" style="display: none;">
      <input type="number" name="nbestim3" placeholder="Pied carré"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "selectedIndex" of your select.

```
var nbestimId = "nbestim" + (nameSelect.selectedIndex + 1);
document.getElementById(nbestimId).style.display = "block";
```

Did not test it.
Also you have to hide the other two, i suppose.

Comment: i don't understand what this is for ? like i said i'm a real noob when it comes to javascript :'(